# Reset Zsh config?

Tags: zsh

Yesterday I installed Zsh, and tried to configure some things, but somehow everything is messed up. A lot of commands do not work, I've done `PROMPT` in ~/.zshrc but it does not work correctly either.

For example when I am trying to search for something:
[image]

Now as you can see I also don't have the prompt name even though I added the `PROMPT="...."` configuration in the `~/.zshrc` file.

Is it possible to somehow reset the whole configuration?

```
zsh  echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/mosquito/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.80/bin:/home/mosquito/HP_Fortify/HP_Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_3.80/bin



zsh  cat /etc/shells
/etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Comment: That seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are "a lot of commands"? Your `find` is working, but just does not do what you excpected: Because the `*` are not quoted ('escaped'), `zsh` is trying (and failing) to find files matching `*zsh*` in the current directory (`~`, hidden files - like `~/.zshrc` - are excluded). Try `find / -name '*zsh*'` instead. As for resetting: if you only ever changed `~/.zshrc` you may just delete it and start from fresh.

Comment: You are right sir about find. Anyways, I deleted zshrc, how do I get fresh one?

Comment: From your terminal type  echo $(which zsh) please and post result.

Comment: I updated main question with info you asked. Also `zsh` does not do anything. `➜  zsh  echo $(which zsh)
/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: Ok, you path is good and your zsh appears to be OK except for your .zshrc.  Having deleted the file from Terminal just enter "zsh" and see if it will prompt you with the "new user screen"

Comment: As I said `zsh` does not have any effect sir.

Comment: I tried chat and it failed so I have to post here.  echo $SHELL, if the result is zsh, then enter ls -la from your home directory and check for .zshrc file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15128/discussion-between-user1880405-and-rcf-u14-04).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To reset your zsh configuration, remove all instances of .zshrc and any .zshrc.??? swap files you may have left over from previous edits.

```
rm -f ~/.zshrc*
```

Then, close your terminal session and re-open. You should get the "new user" screen.
Select the options from the menu prompts to create a new recommended starting point for your .zshrc configuration and add any prompts or other options you need.

That should do it.

Just be sure that zsh is in /etc/shells file.

```
which zsh
```

Will verify the path to your zsh shell.

Set the default shell to zsh, if not already done with

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

Verify your FPATH contains the zsh functions and site-functions folders.

Hopefully, all is well.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up copying the contents from the template file in the github repo into my ~/.zshrc file that I'd messed up, found here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template

Answer (score 4):

I would just like to add, that in case you are using something like `oh-my-zsh`, then instead of just deleting the `.zshrc` file, You need to copy the standard default `.zshrc` file.

Use this command instead:

`cp ~/.oh-my-zsh/templates/zshrc.zsh-template ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Thanks I hosed my install and this is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it seems there is now (in zsh 5.8) a 'proper' method to reset the configuration wizard (for want of a better word).

I've just used `rm .zshrc` to reset the wizard on a new install as described in [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483954/1667679). After I logged out and back in, the wizard ran again, allowing me to set the various options. After I saved everything, it told me:

```
The function will not be run in future, but you can run
it yourself as follows:
  autoload -Uz zsh-newuser-install
  zsh-newuser-install -f
```

I haven't tried either method myself, but it looks like they will do the job. I don't know what the difference between the two methods is, but I'd guess that the first one will run the next time you log in and that the second one will run immediately.

[The set-up instructions](https://www.tecmint.com/install-zsh-in-ubuntu/) also mention these, showing the message in [an image of the terminal when the set-up is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G92GE.png).