# deleted .zshrc file and messed up few things

Tags: command-line, zsh

Oh-My-Zsh was working fine. I was editing `.zshrc` file and somethings messed up. Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483927/reset-zsh-config) post I tried to reset my zsh. I deleted everything related to zsh.

ran:

`sudo apt-get purge zsh` and `sudo apt-get autoremove zsh`

Tried to delete it from `/usr/bin` and `/etc/shells` and then tried to re-install zsh with `apt-get` but `.zshrc` didn't came back. I know I am stupid this here but I had no idea to get it fixed. Please help. I have Oh-My-Zsh already installed but then I messed the ZSH Shell.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to do exactly - if you are looking for the default `~/.zshrc` that gets created the first time a user invokes `zsh`, then it appears to be copied from `/etc/zsh/newuser.zshrc.recommended`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `.zshrc` doesn't come back. Use your backup.

A new file will be created, if you start `zsh` and follow the configuration steps.

Or start the installation and configuration of oh-my-zsh again. [Here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/README.markdown) are the installation steps.

Comment: I don't have backup. Where would I look for backup .zshrc

Comment: No backup? That's bad.

Comment: I tried to copy paste some zsh files from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171563/whats-in-your-zshrc

But they have syntax errors. When I type `source .zshrc`

Comment: Use the official installation steps. I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok so installation of oh-my-zsh will restore it? But I have oh-my-zsh already installed. Will it not create any problem?

Comment: No, there are no problems.

Comment: The link to README is broken, please change to https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4):

So I found a good solution from another thread about `.bash_profile` that applies here too. If you have a terminal window still open with the previous config:

To get back the defined vars and functions:

```
$ declare > ~/.zshrc.recovered
```

And to get back aliases

```
$ alias >> ~/.zshrc.recovered
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it gets installed when you install oh-my-zsh. Regardless, here is a basic one from my own oh-my-zsh setup:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
  export ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh
export TERM="xterm-256color"

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k"

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
CASE_SENSITIVE="false"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

# User configuration

  export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/dsa_id"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Comment: looks like you are using xterm. Will this line `export TERM="xterm-256color"
` won't create any issue with basic Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: It just makes the theme I'm using look better. If you want to use it as is, you'll have to download powerlevel9k(from github)'s theme file into `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/`

Otherwise, there are other themes preinstalled. Think they're in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes`